# specifying a random association object in factory_girl definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Is there a way in `factory_girl` to specify a random instance that an association should point to?  For example, I have a `Like` object which `belongs_to` one `User` and one `SocialUnit`.  I want the factory for `Like` to pick a random existing `User` and a random `SocialUnit` to like, instead of just generating a new one.  The below snippet sort of works:

```
Factory.define :like do |f|
  if User.all.count > 0
    f.user User.all.sort_by{ rand }.first
  else
    f.association :user
  end
end
```

It indeed picks a random user, but it seems like the random user only gets picked once, because running this

```
def create_hauls
  5.times do |i|
    Factory(:haul)
  end
end
```

creates a bunch of likes all with the same user.  I guess that makes sense... the factory gets defined once, and then reused a bunch of times.

I could use a sequence to force randomness; is there a way to define it within the factory definition, or is the sequence the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use a [lazy attribute](http://rdoc.info/projects/thoughtbot/factory_girl) instead of defining the user when the factory is defined. This will define the user each time the factory is used instead.

`f.user { (User.all.count > 0 ? User.all.sort_by{ rand }.first : Factory.create(:user)) }`

Comment: ah, thanks.  i had implemented a solution with a sequence (replacing `if User.all.count > 0` in my snippet with `Factory.next(:random_user)`, but looking back, that was wrong because it was still going to check whether `User.all.count > 0` only once.  Thanks for the help!